# How to query and retrieve information from a Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

I am putting information from a folder into a datatable. I'm putting the info into the datatable using the following code line:

dtUpgradeFileInfo.Rows.Add(nums[0],nums[1],nums[2],test1);

It appears to be working but I'm not as familiar with datatables in C# as I am in VB. How would i search the datatable where the first column has a certain value and the third column has the highest value in case there are multiple rows with the same value in the first column. I am also unsure of how to retrieve the info once I've found the row I need. The type for each column is int,int,int,string respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by VB you mean *VB.NET* and not something like VB6, then the code to work with DataTables (as opposed to legacy VB recordsets) will be the same in C#. Rather, the methods you would employ, obviously the syntax will be differently because it's C#. There's semi-colons and brackets where you might except parentheses. But they're using the same objects, calling the same methods.

Anyway, you could do this (C# 3.0+)

```
DataRow matchingRow = (from DataRow row in dtUpgradeFileInfo.Rows
                       where (int)row["Column1"] == yourValue
                       orderby (int)row["Column3"] descending
                       select row).FirstOrDefault();

if (matchingRow != null)
{
    // get to work
}
```

And for a non-LINQ answer (any version of C#)

```
string filter = "Column1 = " + yourValue.ToString();
string sortOrder = "Column3 desc";

dtUpgradeFileInfo.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
dtUpgradeFileInfo.DefaultView.Sort = sortOrder;
DataRow myRow = null;
DataTable filteredTable = dtUpgradeFileInfo.DefaultView.ToTable();
if (filteredTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    myRow = filteredTable.Rows[0];

if (myRow != null)
{
    // get to work
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I can't get this to work. Error lines everywhere asking for semicolons in the middle of the lines and invalid ) and invalid in.

Comment: And VB.Net 2008 is what i'm used to using.

Comment: Sorry, typo, wasn't typing in an IDE. If you have more issues, this expects that you have `using System.Data;` and `using System.Linq;` in your file.

Comment: @Bryan, did not notice your C# 2.0 tag earlier. I have added code that should work in that environment.